# Copy range and store them on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I think this is not a too difficult task to do, but the problem is that I actually don't know anything about programming and I need to do this on my current job. This is my issue:

The problem is that I have to develop a Macro, and assign it to a button, that copies range E3:K14 from Page 1(sheet1) and paste it on A1 on Page 2(sheet2). This first task is rather easy, but the problem comes when if I hit again the button's assigned Macro it has to copy the same range from Page 1 and paste it on Page 2 but if the first has to check if there already something pasted on A1, if there is, then it must copy it on cell I1 and if I click the button again to Q1 and so on.

When the range is pasted it must be pasted with "Paste Vales" option.

If someone could just put me the exact code (with some comments if possible) for me just to paste it would be really helpful.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you can use this code to get the last column with data, this is the key for solve your problem.

```
Sub SelectLast()
  Dim LastColumn As Long
  With ActiveSheet
    LastColumn = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
  End With
  MsgBox LastColumn

  Cells(18, LastColumn + 2).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("E3:K14").Copy .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.End(xlUp).Row) + 1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Explanation :**

- Have used the Range Copy Method and provided a destination where to
  paste.
- `.Range("A" & .Rows.End(xlUp).Row) + 1` checks for last used cell in sheet2 column A and adds 1 so that data is pasted on last used row.(Assuming the column E does not have blank cells)

Comment: It works once, but when I click on it agian y just rewrites it, also it pastes them directly so there a #REF! error.

Comment: @user2433379 In `Range("E3:K14")` which of the column have values with no blank cells in it ?

Comment: I also added some random numbers on range A2 to G12 on Page 2(sheet2) to see if the code jumped to the column I1 but it pasted the values on A21 witht he same #REF! error.

Comment: All cells have values just from H3 to H14 there's empty cells

Comment: @user2433379  I mean column wise like `Range("E3:E14")`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what do you meant on your previous comment, on the expresion: Range("E3:E14") there's formulas equal to a number

Comment: @user2433379 Can you upload a screenshot of your data `Range("E3:K14")` and upload on tinypic.com and provide me with a link. Thanks

Comment: http://s1364.photobucket.com/user/Pato_Mendoza/media/ExcelRange_zps070561a8.png.html?sort=3&o=0